# how to get rid of error "'float' object has no attribute 'exp'"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I create a list that stores some information like this:

```
import numpy as np

moves = [(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 1), (2, 3), (2, 4)]

wins = [i for i in range(2 * len(moves))]
playout_number = [23 for i in range(2 * len(moves))]

data = [list(map(lambda i: moves[i] if divmod(i, len(moves))[0] != 1 else moves[divmod(i, len(moves))[1]],
                       [i for i in range(2 * len(moves))])),
    list(map(lambda i: 1 if i >= len(moves) else 2,
                       [i for i in range(2 * len(moves))])),
    wins,
    playout_number
    ]
table = np.asarray(data)
player1_info = table[:, np.where(table[1, :] == 1)[0].tolist()]
```

The code works well up to here, but when I add the code below:

```
b = np.divide(player1_info[2, :], player1_info[3, :]).reshape(1, player1.shape[1])
print(np.exp(b))
```

It gives out the error: 'float' object has no attribute 'exp'.

How can I rewrite the code to cope with the error?

Comment: I don't know the root cause (it is probably because of those list comprehensions) but `b`'s dtype is object. `np.exp(b.astype('float'))` should work.

Comment: It seems that you're assigned a float number to the `np` name.

Comment: Pretty sure `np.where(table[1, :] == 1)[0].tolist()` can be spelt simply `table[1, :] == 1` in the context you have there

Comment: yes, `table[1, :] == 1` does the same thing, but the error is not solved yet.

Answer (score 3):

I used `np.float64` like this:

```
b = np.divide(player1_info[2, :], player1_info[3, :])
b = np.float64(b)
print(np.exp(b))
```

Thanks to @Eric I changed `table[:, np.where(table[1, :] == 1)[0].tolist()]` simply to `table[:, table[1, :] == 2]`. 
The error didn't show up and it gave out the right answer.
I think the list elements were unknown to `np.exp` and it couldn't calculate it.